# Can I use my beloved Calendar Extender in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I love the calendar extender, but I am unable to use it in my MVC app.  How do I connect the calendar extender to a textbox in MVC... or add the extender at all for that matter?

Old Way...

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
...
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="DateCheck">
</asp:TextBox>
...
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
...
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate1">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - if you use the Microsoft Ajax libraries. Link [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/). Calandar code [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20Calendar%20Control.ashx).

If you go to Stephen Walthers bolg - [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/Default.aspx) I'm sure there's an example of using the server side controls if memory serves me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the JQuery UI datepicker?
See [JQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: Preference thing, I think the CalendarExtender looks better. Not just css.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your view like a web form, or use a web form within the MVC application, as it requires a form with runat server and a scriptmanager on the view page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  A pretty helpful step by step link that gave me EXACTLY what I want...[CodeSprouts.com](http://www.codesprouts.com/post/Creating-A-DatePicker-Extension-In-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) helped me out alot.  Thanks for the directions!!!